# Rotate/Translate a plane from one normal to another

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, linear-algebra

I have a plane with its normal as (0,1,0), i.e. it's an x-z plane. I have a new normal and distance. I want to convert my original plane to the new plane normal/distance.

To calculate the rotation, I simply took the cross product of the two normals, and got the angle by doing the dot products. Then I rotated it. How do I move the plane along the new normal? If my original plane originates at (0,0,0), do I just translate it by (Nx*d, Ny*d, Nz*d) (where N = new normal, and d = distance from the origin)?

Comment: sounds right to me, assuming the original plane passes through the origin...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com


Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I move the plane along the new normal?

I think your proposal is correct.

Assume you represent the plane with a **unit normal** and a **distance** which is the distance from origin to the plane. Then, you can do any translation as below,

```
m_distance += m_normal.Dot(translation); \\ translation will be (Nx*d, Ny*d, Nz*d) in your case. 
m_normal; \\ normal stay the same, as translation won't change the direction of the plan.
```

Actually m_distance = m_distance + d in this case.